# Collectionview Showing Different Cell with Different iPad Devices for Custom Calendar

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I’m trying to create a custom calendar in my app and I added the following code.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout:
                        UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width/7, height: 36)

    }
```

But in different iPad devices, the weekdays show more than 7 & and some iPad show 5 days of the week. It's changing the cell size depending on the screen size. But I want to add & days for all iPad screen widths. Then I tried the following

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .pad
    {
    if (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad &&
        (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height == 1366 || UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width == 1366))
    {
    print("iPad Pro : 12.9 inch")
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width/7 + 20, height: 36)
    }
    else if (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad &&
             (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height == 1024 || UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width == 1024))
        {
    print("iPad 2 || iPad Pro : 9.7 inch || iPad Air/iPad Air 2 || iPad Retina ")
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width/7 - 5, height: 36)
    }
    else if (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad &&
             (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height == 1180 || UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width == 1180))
        {
    print("iPad Air 4th gen")
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width/7 + 5, height: 45)
    }
    else if (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad &&
             (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height == 1194 || UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width == 1194))
        {
    print("iPad Pro 11")
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width/7 + 5, height: 45)
    }
    else if (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad &&
             (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height == 1112 || UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width == 1112))
        {
    print("iPad Air 3")
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width/7, height: 45)
    }
    else
        {
        print("iPad 3")
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width/7, height: 45)
        }
    }
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width/7, height: 45)
}
```

For using this most of the iPad devices are getting exactly 7 days cell. But some devices (iPad 5th, 6th, 7th generation) with 1024 screen width still showing 6 days a week. I tried with the simulator.

Comment: I have several questions to help debug this. What is the width of your collection view ? How did you set it - auto layout or frames ? What are some of the random numbers you add like `+20`, `-5` etc when calculating the cell width ? Is it a horizontal or vertical scroll collection view ? Do you set any minimumInteritemSpacing and minimumLineSpacing for the collection view layout ?

Comment: Thank you for your response.  The width of my collection view is 376.5. I added a UI view and added a collection view inside the view and added 0 for leading, trailing, top and bottom are 0. My collection view is inside a table view cell.  Then I added return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width/7, height: 36). But it's not showing every device in the simulator exactly 7 cells. I added the collectionView.frame.size.width/7. So I just tried to add with screen width. For that, I added a custom width for each device.For that I added + 20, -5 etc.

Comment: Can you add the code of how you configure the collection view's layout ? Do you add any `contentInsets`, `minimumInteritemSpacing` or `minimumLineSpacing` ?

Comment: No I'm not added that yet

Comment: CollectionView needs a layout, how did you create the collection view - using storyboard ? If yes, some spacing is automatically given. If you made it using code, show your collection view initialization code

Comment: I created using storyboard

Comment: let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 5
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        collectionView!.collectionViewLayout = layout                                                I added this in awakeFromNib(). Now also it's working fine only in iPad mini

Comment: So check the properties in storyboard for `insets` `minimumInteritemSpacing` and `minimumLineSpacing` . Based on your calculations above, you should set these to 0 or you will not have 7 cells in a row in some situations.

Comment: let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        collectionView!.collectionViewLayout = layout Added this. Now also iPad Pro showing 10 cells

Comment: Ok, I will try to create an example in some time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242641/discussion-between-kavya-and-shawn-frank).

Answer (score 1):

Your answer might work for the time being, however I would recommend against using hard-coded values like `173, 20, 7 etc` which might not work if screen dimensions change or even the orientation.

The main thing to figure out is how much `available width` you actually have to work with before getting the cell dimensions.

Here is what I would do:

```
extension CalendarVC: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
        var availableWidth = collectionView.bounds.size.width
        
        // Remove horizontal insets if any
        if let collectionViewLayout
            = collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        {
            let totalSectionInsets
                = collectionViewLayout.sectionInset.left + collectionViewLayout.sectionInset.right
            
            availableWidth -= totalSectionInsets
            
            // Remove the horizontal spacing between cells, which is a bit tricky
            // The horizontal spacing between cells is the interItemSpacing
            // There will always be numberOfColumns - 1 in spaces between cells
            // For 7 cells, there will be 6 spaces. For 5, there will be 4 etc
            let spaces = numberOfColumns - 1
            let totalSpacing = CGFloat(spaces) * collectionViewLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing
            
            availableWidth -= totalSpacing
        }
        
        // Remove the vertical content insets if any
        let horizontalContentInsets
            = collectionView.contentInset.left + collectionView.contentInset.right
        
        availableWidth -= horizontalContentInsets
        
        // Now we have the actual available width after all the insets and spacing
        // So calculate the cell width
        let cellDimension = availableWidth / CGFloat(numberOfColumns)
        
        // Keep the height same as width to get a square or set it as you wish
        return CGSize(width: cellDimension, height: cellDimension)
    }
}
```

This will give you the following in phones portrait:

[image: CollectionView Calendar Cells Spacing Flow Layout Swift iOS]

Landscape phones

[image: CollectionView Calendar Cells Spacing Flow Layout Swift iOS orientation autolayout]

iPad

[image: iPad UICollectionView Cell calendar columns UICollectionViewFlowLayout]

In all cases you get 7 columns without using random numbers

Here is the full solution:

```
// Cell class, not so important for you
fileprivate class DateCell: UICollectionViewCell
{
    static let reuseIdentifier = "DateCell"
    
    let date = UILabel()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect)
    {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        contentView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        configureLabel()
        layoutIfNeeded()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder)
    {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    private func configureLabel()
    {
        contentView.addSubview(date)
        
        date.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        date.textColor = .black
        date.textAlignment = .center
        date.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        addConstraints([
        
            date.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            date.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
            date.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
            date.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor)
        
        ])
    }
}
```

```
// View Controller
class CalendarVC: UIViewController
{
    var calendarCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    // Number of columns per row
    let numberOfColumns = 7
    
    // Padding between the cells horizontally
    // and vertically
    let padding: CGFloat = 10
    
    let sectionInset: CGFloat = 10
    
    var daysInMonth = 0
    
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        title = "CV Calendar"
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        configureDaysInMonth()
        configureCollectionView()
    }
    
    // I am just getting days of the month, not so important for you
    private func configureDaysInMonth()
    {
        let cal = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        
        // Calculate start and end of the current year (or month with `.month`):
        if let range = cal.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: Date())
        {
            daysInMonth = range.count
        }
    }
    
    private func configureCollectionView()
    {
        calendarCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero,
                                                  collectionViewLayout: createLayout())
        
        calendarCollectionView.register(DateCell.self,
                                        forCellWithReuseIdentifier: DateCell.reuseIdentifier)
        
        calendarCollectionView.dataSource = self
        calendarCollectionView.delegate = self
        calendarCollectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        calendarCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        view.addSubview(calendarCollectionView)
        
        // Collection view auto layout
        view.addConstraints([
        
            calendarCollectionView.leadingAnchor
                .constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor,
                            constant: 0),
            
            calendarCollectionView.topAnchor
                .constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor,
                            constant: 0),
            
            calendarCollectionView.trailingAnchor
                .constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor,
                            constant: 0),
            
            calendarCollectionView.bottomAnchor
                .constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor,
                            constant: 0)
            
        ])
    }
    
    private func createLayout() -> UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    {
        let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = padding
        flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = padding
        flowLayout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: sectionInset,
                                               left: 0,
                                               bottom: 0,
                                               right: 0)
        
        return flowLayout
    }
}
```

```
// UICollectionView DataSource, not too important for you
extension CalendarVC: UICollectionViewDataSource
{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        daysInMonth
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell
            = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: DateCell.reuseIdentifier,
                                                 for: indexPath) as! DateCell
        
        cell.date.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1)"
        
        return cell
    }
}
```

```
// UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, same as above
extension CalendarVC: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
        var availableWidth = collectionView.bounds.size.width
        
        // Remove horizontal insets if any
        if let collectionViewLayout
            = collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        {
            let totalSectionInsets
                = collectionViewLayout.sectionInset.left + collectionViewLayout.sectionInset.right
            
            availableWidth -= totalSectionInsets
            
            // Remove the horizontal spacing between cells, which is a bit tricky
            // The horizontal spacing between cells is the interItemSpacing
            // There will always be numberOfColumns - 1 in spaces between cells
            // For 7 cells, there will be 6 spaces. For 5, there will be 4 etc
            let spaces = numberOfColumns - 1
            let totalSpacing = CGFloat(spaces) * collectionViewLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing
            
            availableWidth -= totalSpacing
        }
        
        // Remove the vertical content insets if any
        let horizontalContentInsets
            = collectionView.contentInset.left + collectionView.contentInset.right
        
        availableWidth -= horizontalContentInsets
        
        // Now we have the actual available width after all the insets and spacing
        // So calculate the cell width
        let cellDimension = availableWidth / CGFloat(numberOfColumns)
        
        // Keep the height same as width to get a square or set it as you wish
        return CGSize(width: cellDimension, height: cellDimension)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your support. I will follow this

Answer (score 0):

I got the perfect solution with the following code.

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
return CGSize(width: (self.contentView.frame.width - 173)/7, height: 45)
}